# Should this question have OS/Database tags?

Tags: discussion

It seems like the question [On a dedicated database server, how much memory to reserve for the OS?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/590/on-a-dedicated-database-server-how-much-memory-to-reserve-for-the-os) should be tagged for a particular OS and database.  How can the "Best" answer bubble to the top unless the question is for a particular OS and database?  Which of these answers is best?

- 2-4 GB on Windows/SQL Server.
- 200 MB on Linux.
- 10-20% on MySQL

Certainly not every question requires OS and database tags, but this seems like one that can't adequately be answered with clarity without them.

If it were any other OP I would probably just add a Windows and SQL-Server tag and be done with it, but given the poster I thought I would get feedback from the community.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, these sort of questions should be tailored to one specific database family and one specific OS (that even means differing SQL Express from SQL Developer from SQL Enterprise, etc).

I am not against someone like Leigh or one of the other regulars re-targeting this question with an edit and then re-asking for the other platforms. We haven't seen Dan Grossman for a year and a half almost, so I doubt we can get him to come back to "migrate" his answers to another post, but if you have a compelling question that that's a great answer to, I can probably beg the devs to move that one answer after showing this post.

Let's get some other posts up (if we're going to migrate answers) and then try to reach out to him.

Now the question becomes, do we need to ask Q those for other platforms and seed answers, or retarget this Q to MS products and stop?

Comment: I've added the tags.  As for re-asking for other platforms I'll leave that to someone who wants an answer to that question.